# Need help extracting elements from a list

Tags: python, list

```
templineNums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,21,22,23,24 ... 1000]
splitLines = [24, 36, 28, 30 .. ]
```

Using the elements in the splitLines list, I need too print that number (split line elements) of templineNums indicies.

For example, the first element of splitLines is 24, which mean i need to print the first 24 elements of templineNums. Then i need to keep looping through the element of splitLines. The next element is 36, which means I need the next 36 elements of where i last left off from the previous index (i.e [24:61. 61 because it is "exclusive"). I need to keep doing this until i loop through all of the elements in splitLines and print out that number of elements from templineNums.

How may I do this? Note: There will not be an array out of bounds error because templineNums has over 1000+ numbers in the list and splitLines will not go past that.
Thanks!

Comment: This looks like homework.  What have you tried on your own?  Remember that `templineNums[0:24]` and `templineNums[24:60]` and `templineNums[60:88]` will give you what you want.  Also remember that Python's end indexing is ALSO exclusive.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? It sounds like you've described exactly what you need to do. Have you made any attempt at all?

Comment: Use a loop where you keep incrementing the start index by the `splitLines` element. Then use that starting index and the current current element as the range of the list slice.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer to your question and It is a good question I don't know why the other didn't like

```
templineNums = list(range(1,1000))
splitLines = [24, 36, 28, 30 ] 

last=0
for i in splitLines:
    print(templineNums[last:last+i])
    last+=i
```

output

```
In [9]: templineNums = list(range(1,1000))
   ...: splitLines = [24, 36, 28, 30 ]
   ...:
   ...: last=0
   ...: for i in splitLines:
   ...:     print(templineNums[last:last+i])
   ...:     last+=i
   ...:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
[61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88]
[89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118]
```